# Where to find the service manual for Early 2008 Mac Pro 2008 (A1186)?

Tags: mac

I have an early 2008 Mac Pro, and I’m trying to find the service manual for it online, but I can’t find it.

Anyone has any clue at all as to where I could find it?

Answer (score 1):

Web search for `mac pro a1186 service manual file:pdf` yielded this as the first result:

- http://tim.id.au/laptops/apple/macpro/macpro_early2008.pdf